# filename character substitution

Tags: linux, grep

I have several thousand files that I need to rename / mv by removing the a set of characters from the start of the file name.

The file names concerned have the character f followed a numeric sequence, an underscore the the file name.  The file name can include alhpa numeric and underscores.  For example, f1234567_this_is_a_file.doc, or f987654321_mine.xlsx

The number of numeric values can vary but is always followed by the underscore, however the filename it self can contain underscores also.

I have tried very perl scripts, and using grep but all to no avail.  Is there a way to to this.  The other issue is that the file name may also contain () @ & etc.

I can get s list of the file using egrep -i "(f[0-9]+_)" and using this to parse out the first section and do a rename of the file, but this is not working.

Thanks

MORE:
I did an ls -1 into a file so that I had a list of all 10000 file names.  I used egrep -i "(f[0-9]+*)" on that list of files to give me a list of the files that require name changes (about 3000).

My perl script then used the list of files get the first part of the file name ($pre) (eg f123456*) by doing a cut -d'*' -f 1.  I also got the remainder of the file name ($post) using cut -d'*' -f2- .  I then generated a move statement using mv $pre $post.  I output that to a file and executed it yet none of the files got renamed.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, and give more details about exactly what you mean when you say they didn't work:  what were the inputs, what output did you expect, what actually happened?

Comment: Is there rename(1) on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Parameter Expansion in bash. Here is simple script:

```
for name in *; do
    mv "${name}" "${name#f[0-9]*_}"
done
```

It will remove the leading `f`, numbers and `_`. Modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Innocent Bystander.  That was exactly what I was after.  yet again, I was trying to over complicate things.  Thanks